# Class de Aplicação PHP

Tags: php

No PHP existe alguma classe que fica funcionando até por exemplo eu fechar a aba do meu navegador, sem ser cookie,a session não serve pois morre quando termina a sessão, gostaria de saber se existe alguma classe que eu possa estender de forma que eu consiga guardar alguns valores até que o navegador ou a aba seja fechado, assim como teria para Android a classe Application.

Comment: Você pode guardar as variáveis em uma sessions e usar um JavaScript para fazer um load ajax automático a cada x minutos, para manter a session viva...

Comment: Nesse caso é melhor cookie se for assim, que não precisa ficar rodando ajax. Só era mais uma curiosidade que possui em outras linguagens gostaria de saber se existe em PHP

Comment: Nesse caso cookie é a melhor solução!

Comment: Serializar alguma classe não seria uma solução?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não, o PHP trata cada requisição de forma isolada, a única forma de trocar dados entre sessões são cookies, sessions ou uma fonte de dados externo(banco de dados, arquivos, etc).

Mais informações na documentação:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.sessions.php

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.cookies.php

Answer (score 0):

não pode, mas você pode usar o gerenciador de tarefas, no Linux é o Cron.
veja esse tutorial pode ser útil.
http://www.deivison.com.br/como-agendar-tarefas-php-no-cron-do-cpanel/